# How to center the navigation bar on my blog?

Tags: html, css, menu, center, blogger

How can I center the navigation bar of my Blogger blog? It's currently on the left, but I want it centered. [template](https://azonstore-bloggertheme9.blogspot.com/)

I tried putting

text-align:center;} and align-items:center;} almost everywhere in the navigation menu code, also  but nothing happens...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
.containerclass {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
}
```

Comment: I love you! It worked!